# PHPCurl - Output to XML?

Tags: php, xml, curl, sitemap, web-crawler

I am using PHPCurl and the example.php from: http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/example.html

I would like to have the sitemap links that are generated output to an XML file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should have already a result from the crawl execution, if you can post it here, it will be easier to help you. In between, you should read a bit about DOM in the php documentation section.

Comment: sure, I have it working with the following to create the .xml and all I just need it to put the data in it's format into the file now...

Comment: The code is too large could you ping me?

Comment: or you could actually see it at http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/example.html

Comment: you can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or any similar service

Comment: can you post here or in pastebin a dump of the $report (i'm using the same variable name of the example)?

Comment: I meant the output of the execution, not the php code from phpcrawl

Comment: This? http://pastebin.com/jR6X2rTz - sorry if I am not understanding exactly which to give you... this is PHPCrawler.class.php.

Comment: You are pasting the php sources of your/phpcrawl code. What we need, is the result of executing the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If what you get from executing the script from PHPcrawl is already XML code, and is in the format that you like, you only have to write it to a file with `fwrite` or any other option that you prefer.

If the XML you get is not what you want, you may process it wit `preg_replace` or any other similar tool.

You may also use XSL to process the XML, generate another one and then use `fwrite` to save it.

Comment: I will look into that...although I am having the issue with getting it to just write the data (xml form)...but do have it creating the file correctly...

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a sitemap.xml file with [PHPCrawl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpcrawl/forums/forum/307696/topic/6037903/index/page/1).